# Javascript - Add new object into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects

please. I have a cycle with fiance balances. It's an array of objects like:

```js
export const balances = [
type: types.outgoing,
    date: 20220410,
    amount: 282.12,
    category: categories.installments,
    source: 'Debit account',
    destination: 'Leasing company',
  },
  {
    type: types.income,
    date: 20220413,
    amount: 1385.3,
    category: categories.job,
    source: 'My employeer',
    destination: 'Debit account',
  },
  ...
]
```

etc...

As you can see, I have a **categories** there which means that I have in cycle every transaction in `balances` and I must create separate category for each of them with total amount for each category, count of items in category and with detailed transactions for each category. I'm using `array.forEach()` cycle:

```js
balances.forEach((balance) => {

  // Checking if category already exists in my array of categories
  let categoryIndex = categories.findIndex((category) => category.category === balance.category)

  // Create details of transaction
  let transactionDetail = {
    date: balance.date,
    amount: balance.amount,
    source: balance.source,
    destination: balance.destination,
  }

  // If category already exists, just calculate total and add new object into array details
  if (categoryIndex !== -1) {
    console.log([categories[categoryIndex].details])
    categories[categoryIndex] = {
      type: balance.type,
      category: balance.category,
      amount: categories[categoryIndex].amount + balance.amount,
      count: (categories[categoryIndex].count += 1),

      // This row is wrong. I cannot use this
      details: [categories[categoryIndex].details].push(transactionDetail),
    }
  } else {
    // If category doesn't yet exists, we must create a first values in this category
    categories.push({
      type: balance.type,
      category: balance.category,
      amount: balance.amount,
      count: 1,
      details: [transactionDetail],
    })
  }
}
```

But the row

```js
details: [categories[categoryIndex].details].push(transactionDetail)
```

doesn't work properly. Probably the reason is, that I have sometimes Object as `tyopeof` result and sometimes `undefined`

Row `console.log([categories[categoryIndex].details])` sometimes output:

```js
// Output for
// console.log([categories[categoryIndex].details])
[Array(1)]0: Array(1)
0: {date: 20220414, amount: 410, source: 'xxx', destination: 'yyy'}
length: 1[[Prototype]]: 
Array(0)length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

[2]
0: 2
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Any hiths how can add object `transactionDetail` as a next in existing array? Thank you very much for any advice.

I don't understand. I can concat string if category already exists, add numbers but I cannot add an next object into array of objects.

EDIT: Just changed `transaction` to `trasactionDetail` in explanation.

Comment: OK. The problem is that when I creating it first time the "details" is an object which is OK. But second time it is a number with result = 2. Really don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several errors in your latter block and have corrected them; let me explain the changes I've made.

1. In the line you marked as wrong, you were putting brackets around the values for some reason. `Categories.details` is presumably an array of `TransactionDetail`, so you don't need to further nest it here.  However, if you push into an array, that returns with the number of objects in the array, so when you did this in that line, `details` would ultimately always be populated with a number. Rather, in my version, I split out the existing category you pulled via index as `existing` and simply push the value to its `details` array. This also just cleans up the top half of your condition since one need only reference the properties from the existing object to match against the new values in a cleaner way.
2. You were using `1(categories[categoryIndex].count += 1)` to increase the count. But, you're also setting precisely that object here, so this isn't a good practice. Rather, set the values you intend to use here and commit it all to the `categories` array as one thing, instead of a mismatch of some values setting here, some set differently. I corrected this to a mere `existing.count + 1`.

Here's your updated code in full then:

```js
balances.forEach((balance) => {

  // Checking if category already exists in my array of categories
  let categoryIndex = categories.findIndex(category => category.category === balance.category);

  // Create details of transaction
  let transactionDetail = {
    date: balance.date,
    amount: balance.amount,
    source: balance.source,
    destination: balance.destination,
  };

  // If category already exists, just calculate total and add new object into array details
  if (categoryIndex !== -1) {
    const existing = categories[categoryIndex];
    existing.details.push(transactionDetail);

    categories[categoryIndex] = {
      type: balance.type,
      category: balance.category,
      amount: existing.amount + balance.amount,
      count: existing.count + 1,
      details: existing.details
    };
  } else {
    // If category doesn't yet exists, we must create a first values in this category
    categories.push({
      type: balance.type,
      category: balance.category,
      amount: balance.amount,
      count: 1,
      details: [transactionDetail],
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for advices. Yes, this really helps. Sorry, let of years of backend programming and now... switch to frontend developer :D Thanks again for exmplanation.